# Solve for all $x $ such that $16\sin^{3}x -14\cos^{3}x = \sqrt[3]{\sin x\cos^{8}x + 7\cos^{9}x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, radicals

The original question :

> Find all $x$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $16\sin^3(x) -14\cos^3(x) = \sqrt[3]{\sin x\cos^8(x) + 7\cos^9(x)}$

It's a tough question I've found. I've tried using

$16\tan^3(x) -14  = \sqrt[3]{\tan x  + 7 }$

By inspection, $\tan x=1$ is one of the answers.

but According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2416tan%5E%7B3%7Dx+-14++%3D+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Btanx++%2B+7+%7D%24), $\tan x$ is not equal to $1$.

(Sorry , I've seen later that $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ , but I don't know how to find all roots of the question.)

Can root of unity solve this?

Comment: $\tan x =1 $ clearly works.  More to the point, $x=\frac {\pi}4$.  works in the original form.  You could try to argue that $16z^3-14=\sqrt[3] {z+7}$ has no real solutions other than $z=1$.

Comment: Note that $a^3 - (a-2)(a+1)^2 = 3a+2$, so $(16x^3-14)^3-(x+7) = (16x^3-16)(16x^3-13)^2 + (48x^3 - x - 47)$. What's left after removing the factor $x-1$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(a) = (2a)^3-7$, is bijective and increasing. Since $f(a) - a = (a-1)(8a^2+8a+7)$, the only solution of the equation $f(a) = a$ is $a=1$;  $f(a) > a$ if $a>1$ and $f(a)<a$ if $a<1$. Then the equations $f(f(a)) = a$ and $f(a) = a$ are equivalent. In particular, $f^{-1} (a) = f(a)$ if and only if $a=1$. In the original problem, $a=\tan{x}$.